# How to format a date to the Italian way in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, date

I have got a webpage that get some values from a mysql database, there's also a date value, I need to change it from y-m-d 2015-03-12 to d-m-y 12-03-2015 or better in for example Monday 12 March in italian if it's possibile
how can I do?

This is what I tried:

```
      $data= mysql_result($result,$i,"data");
      $retrieved = '$data';
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $retrieved);
      echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
      $data = $date;
```

Comment: Note that you are using a long since deprecated API (mysql_). See mysqli_/PDO and prepared statements

Comment: check my answer, if it help you don't forget check as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format in `createFromFormat` must be `Y-m-d` and the format in `$date->format()` must be `d-m-Y` you must change your formats like this:

```
<?php

  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2015-03-12');
  $date_out = $date->format('d-m-Y');
  echo $date_out; //output 12-03-2015

  echo "<br>\n";

  $date_out = $date->format('l d F');
  echo $date_out; //output Thursday 12 March


?>
```

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Now after you posted this code you may want to add an answer to this question! Right now this is only code! Same as `echo "xy";`